# How to bubblesort a structure in c with reference to name alphabetically

Tags: c, struct, structure, bubble-sort

Actually I want to bubble sort entire records with respect to name(in Alphabetical order). but compiler gives error of "invalid array assignment".
please check the code given below, especially the bubblesort part.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

struct form {
    char name[20], employ[20], gend[20], email[20], father[20];
    int num, serial;

} a[11];

main() {

    int c, tmp, d;

    for (c = 0; c < 10; c++) {

        printf("Employ#:");
        scanf("%d", &a[c].serial);
        printf("Enter Name:");
        scanf("%s", &a[c].name);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Enter Father Name:");
        scanf("%s", &a[c].father);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Enter Email.Id:");
        scanf("%s", &a[c].email);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Enter employment#:");
        scanf("%s", &a[c].employ);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Enter Gender:");
        scanf("%s", &a[c].gend);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Enter Number:");
        scanf("%d", &a[c].num);
        printf("\n");

    }


    //Bubblesorting


    int i, j, temp;
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (a[i].name[0] < a[i + 1].name[0]) {
                a[10].serial = a[i].serial;
                a[10].name = a[i].name;
                a[10].father = a[i].father;
                a[10].email = a[i].email;
                a[10].employ = a[i].employ;
                a[10].gend = a[i].gend;
                a[10].num = a[i].num;

                a[i].serial = a[i + 1].serial;
                a[i].name = a[i + 1].name;
                a[i].father = a[i + 1].father;
                a[i].email = a[i + 1].email;
                a[i].employ = a[i + 1].employ;
                a[i].gend = a[i + 1].gend;
                a[i].num = a[i + 1].num;

                a[i + 1].serial = a[10].serial;
                a[i + 1].name = a[10].name;
                a[i + 1].father = a[10].father;
                a[i + 1].email = a[10].email;
                a[i + 1].employ = a[10].employ;
                a[i + 1].gend = a[10].gend;
                a[i + 1].num = a[10].num;

            }
        }
    }


    system("cls");

    printf("\nEmployee#\tName\tFather Name\tEmail\t\t\a[10]loyement#\tGender\tContact#");

    for (c = 0; c < 10; c++) {

        printf("\n\t%d\t", a[c].serial);

        printf("%s\t", a[c].name);

        printf("   %s\t", a[c].father);

        printf("%s\t", a[c].email);

        printf("\t%s\t", a[c].employ);

        printf("%s\t", a[c].gend);

        printf("%d\t", a[c].num);

    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: What a mess this post is. You couldn't even pick a language? Make the code barely readable?

Comment: To which line of your code the error message ha been generated? Did you check that line of your code?

Comment: please just check the logic of bubblesort and tell me the mistake.

Comment: at this line, a[10].name = a[i].name;

Comment: @kikkaz69 First, you can swap the entire structure, not every element one at a time.  If you did that, then you rid yourself of the string copying errors.  Then after that, fix the bubble sort itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your bubble sort looks nothing like one that you would find in any documentation concerning sorting.  It should be a very simple doubly-nested loop and comparing two items in the inner loop and swapping them if they're out of order.

Second, to sort alphabetically, you're supposed to compare the entire string, not just the first letter.  Since you didn't pick a language, let's assume it is `C` for the moment.  You would use `strcmp` to compare C-style strings.

Last, you don't need to swap one item in your struct at a time.  You can swap the entire struct.

```
#include <string.h>
//...
int i, j, temp;
int num_items = 10;
for (j = 0; j < num_items - 1; j++) 
{
     for (i = 0; i < num_items - 1; i++) 
     {
            if ( strcmp(a[i].name, a[i + 1].name ) > 0) 
            {
                form temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
            }
     }
}
```

Also, there is no need to make your array artificially have more items than necessary.  You declared your array as having 11 items, and I guess the reason was to make the bubble sort work.

There is no reason to declare 11 items.  Just declare it as 10 items and write the bubble sort correctly (note that the difference in the loop constraints).  What if the `form` struct was very large?  You would have declared 1 more item than necessary, using memory for no reason whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get the error is because, you are trying to copy array of characters using the assignment operator.

For example ::

```
int a[10], b[10];
b = a;
```

is a wrong way to assign `a` to `b`, which you are doing everywhere in your code, which is giving the error *"invalid array assignment"*.

Moreover, I do not understand why you are doing so much hardwork in copying all the variable of the `struct` like this, simply doing this would help as well.

```
for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (a[i].name[0] < a[i + 1].name[0]) {
            a[10] = a[i];
            a[i] = a[i+1];
            a[i+1] = a[10];    
         }
     }
}
```

Moreover, you compare the 2 structs, based on the 1st character of their `name[]`. So, in case you have 2 names like "ABD" and "ACD" in your `a` array, they do not get sorted, so you shall try modifying your criteria on which you sort 2 objects.

Comment: Thankyou sir. I tried it first, but it gave an error. But now it's resolved.

Comment: @kikkaz69 Glad I could help :D